# How can I replay or just play custom-crafted Bluetooth low energy packets?

Tags: security, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I want to do some experiments on BLE IoT devices. My goal to create/modify existing Bluetooth packets and play them to the devices.

Comment: i think you want something like https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2016/september/introducing-blesuite-and-ble-replay-python-tools-for-rapid-assessment-of-bluetooth-low-energy-peripherals/